# Price update working but not with multiple select and discounting the price at the end

Tags: javascript, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have multiple dropdown lists calculating a total price at the end, it works great apart from a few issues.

Firstly, I would like to add further prices to it, so it should read:

Total  : £20.97

V.A.T : £4.19

Total Amount : £25.16

I'm sure this is simple but i cannot think how?

Secondly - It only works on a single selection drop down lists, if i want to select multiple options in one list, it will only calculate one

Here's the code i use to calculate the price:

```javascript
$(function(){
    $(".calculate").on("change", function(){
        var total = 0;
        $('.calculate').each(function() {
            if($(this).val() != 0) {
                total += parseFloat($(this).val());
            }
        });
        $('#total').text('£' + total.toFixed(2));
    });

});//]]>
```

Thirdly, there are about 8 dropdown lists but i want the last one to discount the total price instead of adding to it, the code above takes the price from option value of each selection and so will the discount amount (In the discount column in the database, it's written as 10%.

So basically, after 7 lists i should have a total of i.e. £20.97 then once the last list is selected, it should replace the price with a discount amount i.e. (-10%) £18.87

I'm so close to finishing this but i can't get over the last hurdle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a SELECT allows multiple selections the jQuery val() function returns an array of values. So your code needs to detect if val() returns and array and if so loop the array and add all those items. Here is one way:

```
$('.calculate').each(function() {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    if (currentValue.length != undefined) {
        for (var i = 0; i < currentValue.length; i++) {
            if (currentValue[i] != 0) {
                total += parseFloat(currentValue[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else if(currentValue != 0) {
        total += parseFloat(currentValue);
    }
});
```

That should take care of multiple select options. For the discount, just get the value of your final SELECT and apply your discount:

```
var discount = parseFloat($('.discount').val()) / 100;
total = total - (total * discount);
```

Comment: Hi David,  i cannot get you cod to work, i've been playing with it for ages and nothing, could you do a fiddle for me as i'm sure I'm missing something simple, thanks

Comment: @user1221565, How about this. Why don't you create a fiddle that contains your current logic and I'll edit your fiddle to apply my logic.

Comment: Hi David, great idea, please follow the link http://jsfiddle.net/tzWgb/4/ I've got it working to a point but not inserted your code so you can see what i'm working with. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, you weren't missing something. My logic wasn't quite right. Here is the new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzWgb/11/

Comment: Hi David, thanks for getting back to me, It worked perfect, i had to play about with it a little to get it to work with what i currently had as i get all the info from mysql but it's all working now including the discount part at the end, Here's a working code for anyone following. http://jsfiddle.net/vkXpm/2/

Answer (score 0):

Is the Javascript pulling the values from the DDL from the Database or hard-coded into the form?

the computation for the % is 20.97 *0.10. Since the 10% is hard-coded this should work for the final drop down list.

Also, other than adding values to the form, and the computation for percentage, I'm not sure where the problem is, maybe some more information would be of value...